# Grails spring security rest inject tokenGenerator

Tags: grails, jwt, spring-security-rest

I have a similar requirement like this post mentioned. [:REST spring security - Manually authenticating a new user and getting access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543592/rest-spring-security-manually-authenticating-a-new-user-and-getting-access-to)

According to the accepted answer, the codes will be like:

```
class RegisterController {

    def springSecurityService
    def tokenGenerator
    def tokenStorageService

    def register() {
         //do stuff
         springSecurityService.reauthenticate(username)
         String tokenValue = tokenGenerator.generateToken()
         tokenStorageService.storeToken(tokenValue, springSecurityService.principal)

         redirect url: "http://example.org/?access_token=${tokenValue}"
    } 
}
```

I tried but it didn't work for me. It seems the TokenGenerator implementation class is not injected right. I understand the default implementation in grails-spring-security-rest TokenGenerator will be the JWT but wonder where should I register or config it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to use the `"tokenGenerator"` then you need to register it under the `"resources.groovy"` like below

```
// creating the bean of token generator
tokenGenerator(SecureRandomTokenGenerator)
```

and then inject it into your controller or service like below

```
class RegisterController {

def springSecurityService
def tokenGenerator
def tokenStorageService

    def register() {
         //do stuff
         springSecurityService.reauthenticate(username)
         String tokenValue = tokenGenerator.generateToken()
         tokenStorageService.storeToken(tokenValue, springSecurityService.principal)

         redirect url: "http://example.org/?access_token=${tokenValue}"
    }
}
```

I have followed the same example (with slight modification) and its working as expected.

I have used the `"userDetailsService"` for generating user instance instead of `"springSecurityService.reauthenticate(username)"`

So my function looks like below.

```
/**
 * For generating the access token for the user
 *
 * @param userName : Holds the username of the user
 *
 * @return : access token
 */
String generateAccessToken(String userName){
    String tokenValue

    try{
        //load user details
        def userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userName)

        //generate access token
        tokenValue = tokenGenerator.generateAccessToken(userDetails).accessToken

        //store access token
        tokenStorageService.storeToken(tokenValue, userDetails)
    } catch (Exception e){
       //Exception handling code
    }

    return tokenValue
}
```

Comment: Could I do the same with `tokenStorageService`?

Comment: Is there a way to do this to generate a signed JWT?